# ORDER sql query is not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a MySQLi query in PHP to a database that I have full of NHL Players and their projected stats/positions.

This is my query string - my goal is for it to return the top 10 projected goal scorers:

```
$goalSQL = 'SELECT * FROM players ORDER BY G LIMIT 10';
```

In my table, G is the column which holds the projected goal count for every player. I also have a column called "Position" which holds the position for every player (G, LW, RW, C, D).

However, I get back an object containing 10 goalies. I am guessing that the SQL is somehow taking my `ORDER BY G` to mean `order by Position:G`, but in reality I have no clue what is going wrong.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess, goalies have the *lowest* projected goal count.  Try using `desc`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM players p
ORDER BY p.G DESC
LIMIT 10;
```